# how to create log in specific location when using log4j in java desktop application

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j in Eclipse for logging messages in a java desktop application. I want that the log should be created in a specific folder (Specifically, in the folder which contains source folder 'src' and classes folder 'bin').

Is it possible to set this in log4j.properties? How to ensure that log is created at this location only?

Comment: you need to set the property `log4j.appender.logfile.File`

Comment: Don't forget to read - Log4j Best practices - http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html

Comment: Updated link for above comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110623160536/http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would go with Saket's reply. But instead of hardcoding the location its always better to have a relative path.

If you started your application from a main method from a class called Launcher for example and this is the structure of your Eclipse Project directory:

```
Java Project
   src
   bin
```

Then just give your location to be

```
 log4j.appender.R.File=./log/Logfile.log
```

This will create the file under a directory log:

```
Java Project
   src
   bin
   log
     LogFile.log
```

Hope you got it.. 
:)

Comment: Perhaps, you want to group all logs in the correct dir (here is also "server.log"), corresponding to the "domain" where the app runs: #Logs Directory: \glassfish\domains\domain_xyz\logs)
logsDir = ../logs  
log4j.appender.FILE.file=${logsDir}/log4j-app-xyz.log

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html), you could set something like this in your `log4j.properties` file (below I am setting `C:/myapp/src/mylog.log` as my target location - you can change this to your desired location):

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=C:/myapp/src/mylog.log
... (other configurations)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to set it in property file. One example is:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=D:/myapp/mylog.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

**log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=D:/myapp/mylog.log** can be modified to any path on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to create log in a project folder since it gets bigger and bigger in size. Rather you can create it in user directory from which your application is running.

Eg: should be **${user.home}/appName/MyWEB.log** , user generally has right to write in home dir

works for both windows and linux environment.

Comment: what is special with your answer.. there is already a high quality answer