# Storing log files in an eclipse project?

Tags: java, logging

I want to log some values for each object of my program into a flat file or csv file. I was thinking of creating separate folders for each of these Objects and storing their log files in their respective folders. Is this possible ? If yes, then is it advisable ?

As an aside, I was thinking of using some logging API. But, I don't know when it is appropriate to use a logging API. Any advice on that also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest you [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) library for logging. It's easy to archive your issue using it.

Try to declare separate appender for each class:

```
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();
// configure the appender here, with file location, etc
appender.activateOptions();

Logger logger = getRootLogger();
logger.addAppender(appender);
```

### Similar questions:

- [Programmatically creating different log files using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666121/programmatically-creating-different-log-files-using-log4j)
- [Log4j multiple log files and logging in common code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873465/log4j-multiple-log-files-and-logging-in-common-code)

Comment: Thanks. But, can the logging API create a folder inside eclipse and store all the logs there?

Comment: @SuperStar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553899/how-to-create-log-in-specific-location-when-using-log4j-in-java-desktop-applicat